# I'm looking forward to list all the publications or post I have ´liked´ to

Tags: instagram-api, social-likes

I have a doubt, Is it possible to get the total number of my likes in the post of other instagram users(friends)?  (All the post that I have pressed like in a period of time).

In the API documentation of Instagram has only likes received but I need my likes dice.

For example:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked

This API is for getting all the posts you have liked, you cannot get count of just filter by a certain time range, you will just start getting all the liked posts, starting with the most recently liked ones and going back...

Comment: I only see my own posts with this call but I only need my likes in the posts of others instagram users(friends), What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you are in sandbox mode, so u will only see your photos, once u go live u will see all users, u also have to get `public_content` permission